# How to drain a node using kubernetes python client?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to automate kubernetes worker nodes using the official [kubernetes python-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python). I am currently looking for a way to [safely move al the running applications to other nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) . We can do so using "kubectl drain". I did not find a way to simulate that functionality using python client. I am currently looking into Does this library support drain functionality yet?

Answer (score 16):

I found the answer. Python client does have support for draining a node but it is not a single command. "kubectl drain" operation utilizes [Eviction API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#the-eviction-api) to safely delete all the workloads running on a node. The python-client has a function [create_namespaced_pod_eviction](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#create_namespaced_pod_eviction) that safely deletes all the pods in a namespace. However, "safely" depends on the [Pod Disruption Budgets (PDB)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) that you have defined for the apps running on that node.

I am posting this answer hoping that someone might find it useful :)

Comment: Note that there's currently (July 2019) a method to [delete a node](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/release-9.0/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#delete_node) in the python-client.