# Drain K8s Node using Javascript Kubernetes Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using the Javascript [@kubernetes/client-node](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) library and I want to gracefully remove a node from K8s (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757620/how-to-gracefully-remove-a-node-from-kubernetes)).

I've not found any guides or documents showing how this can be done correctly using a K8s client library. The only resource I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592838/how-to-drain-a-node-using-kubernetes-python-client) but it's for the Python client and does not show the "full" code procedure.

How can this be achieved by the K8s Javascript client?